# Powershell New Exchange Distribution List wait or pause before sending email to it

Tags: powershell, wait

I have a script that creates a distro, adds members and then emails it. The issue is that exchange is bouncing the mail. I think it is because of replication.

I would rather not user sleep seconds and have tried 2 different Do while commands. They both pause and do wait with a single XO but when the send mail message goes, exchange bounces it as not found. if I refire the send mail message command a minute later it does go through.

```
#Sleep -seconds 10

do{
     sleep -seconds 1
     $mailboxExists = get-distributiongroup -Identity $emailfwddistro -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |fw IsValid
     write-host "X" -nonewline
 }while (!$mailboxExists)

do{            
     sleep -seconds 1
     $DistroEmailAddress = Get-recipient -Identity ($EmailFwdDistro + '@Domain.com') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |fw IsValid
     Write-host "0" -nonewline
 }while (!$distroEmailAddress)

Send-mailmessage xyz


#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##
```

Comment: sleep seconds 15 seems to do the trick without errors. I would like to figure out the do while way to try to understand what is happening. If for some reason 15 seconds fails in the future I will be in the same boat.

Comment: Don't want to use `sleep -seconds 60` try `sleep -milliseconds 60000` - also add a log file or `start-transcript` command so you can audit for failures later on.  What about a try catch kinda thing

Comment: I need it to finish successfully. The sleep thing might fail with seconds or milliseconds if the server is busy. I would rather try to query whatever the send-mailmessage command is failing on and then send the message once it is ready.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the global address book not having  the information yet.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger - `send-mailmessage` is unlikely to return an error in this instance. The SMTP server will accept the message without validating the recipients. If delivery subsequently fails, a notification will be sent to the address specified in `-from` parameter.

Comment: @Doms - In theory, you could request a positive delivery notification by specifying `-DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess` and then poll the `-from` mailbox until the notification is received. Seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut though.

Answer (score 0):

As per what @Doms said, this is a replication issue but is likely to exist between domain controllers. You can avoid it by checking which DC is being used by your exchange box:

```powershell
Get-ExchangeServer -Status | fl Current*
```

This will return current DC,GC and DC used for configuration.

Then create new Distribution Groups on that DC using `-DomainController` switch and DC returned from previous command.

```powershell
New-DistributionGroup MyGroup -DomainController yourdc.domain.local
```

Comment: It has all 3 DC's as Current and Global but just 03 as the config one. Do I not need that do while command if I use 03 this way?  I am going to test it and post back.

Comment: You can set static DCs/GCs with `Set-ExchangeServer`. This will ensure the Exchange box and `New-DistributionGroup` use the same server.

Comment: I tried making a distro with the domain controller switch and sending an email. it still failed to find the email address. I just went back to the sleep seconds.